# System-wide environment variables for zsh on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, zsh

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04

I'm trying to add some system-wide envvars, I want them to be visible to both bash and zsh(my main shell), I added them to /etc/profile but unfortunately I can't see them in zsh

I found that Ubuntu has a file /etc/environment that's only meant for envvars(as opposed to general scripts) but zsh doesn't honor that file.

When I try to source /etc/profile manually I get the following output(I guess it doesn't parse it to the end)

```
$ source /etc/profile
/etc/profile:5: no matches found: /etc/profile.d/*.sh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual page `zsh(1)` states that zsh reads `/etc/zsh/zprofile`.  You could simply add a command there which sources `/etc/profile`.

Comment: While this answer will work for zsh alone, it's probably not the best solution. Please see my answer.

Comment: Also, `/etc/zsh/zprofile` contains a line (By default on Arch, probably Ubuntu as well) which already sources `/etc/profile`.

Comment: The method I use on Debian is to add export ENVPARAM=ENVPARAMVALUE to /etc/zsh/zshenv.  I do so for NASMENV and it's available from the start of Linux on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer should be to use `/etc/environment` like:

```sh
MYVAR=myvalue
```

because it is shell agnostic. Environment variables set there apply to all shells (sh, bash, zsh, etc.) for all accounts. Reference [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables#Globally) (Also applies to Ubuntu and other distros).

If you tried it and it didn't work, you probably forgot to logout and back in for it to take effect. As for `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, mine already contains (By default) a line which sources `/etc/profile`:

```bsh
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```